# Categorization on basis of boolean flags smells? How to clean it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, categorization

We have a piece of code here to determine the category of an assignment based on a few boolean flags. The author laid it out to resemble a table, but it ended up looking jarring to everyone else. However, none of us know how to make this code more elegant while still looking fairly organized.

Any suggestions? We'd like to get rid of this monstrosity.

```
category =

!optional && !taken && !active                          ? "obligatory overdue"  :
!optional && !taken &&  active                          ? "obligatory fresh"   :
!optional &&  taken &&  active && !cooldown && !locked  ? "obligatory taken"  :
 optional && !taken                                     ? "optional fresh"   :
 optional &&  taken            && !cooldown             ? "optional taken"  :
!optional &&  taken && !active && !cooldown             ? "optional taken" :
!optional &&  taken &&  active &&  cooldown && !locked  ? "cooldown"      :
 optional &&  taken            &&  cooldown             ? "cooldown"     :
!optional &&  taken && !active &&  cooldown             ? "cooldown"    :
!optional &&  taken &&  active              &&  locked  ? "locked"     :  []
```

Comment: I think what the author did was pretty clever, any alternative will end up either with a lot of methods or messy code (you do need to evaluate all flags). This way its fairly easy to understand when a `category` will be assigned. I will definitely put the logic (as it is) into a helper method.

Comment: I tried all the permutations of parameters order and all the `[true, false]` repeated permutations, I couldn't find anything shorter than this code.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the "table" of categories in a *constant* and keep the flag logic there, for example:

```
CATEGORIES = {
  "obligatory overdue" => [
    { optional: false, taken: false, active: false, cooldown: nil, locked: nil }
  ],
  "obligatory fresh" => [
    { optional: false, taken: false, active: true, cooldown: nil, locked: nil }
  ],
  "obligatory taken" => [
    { optional: false, taken: true, active: true, cooldown: false, locked: false }
  ],
  "optional fresh" => [
    { optional: true, taken: false, active: nil, cooldown: nil, locked: nil }
  ],
  "optional taken" => [
    { optional: true, taken: true, active: nil, cooldown: false, locked: nil },
    { optional: false, taken: true, active: false, cooldown: false, locked: nil }
  ],
  "cooldown" => [
    { optional: false, taken: true, active: true, cooldown: true, locked: false },
    { optional: true, taken: true, active: nil, cooldown: true, locked: nil },
    { optional: false, taken: true, active: false, cooldown: true, locked: nil }
  ],
  "locked" => [
    { optional: false, taken: true, active: true, cooldown: nil, locked: true }
  ],
}
```

Then create a method to search in `CATEGORIES` for the right category:

```
def set_category(flags)
  CATEGORIES.find { |k, v| v.include?(flags) }&.[](0)
end
```

Finally, instead of setting flags as multiple variables, set them in a `Hash`, like this:

```
flags = {
  optional: false,
  taken: false,
  active: true,
  cooldown: nil,
  locked: nil
}
```

Now you can set the right category by calling `set_category` with `flags` as a parameter:

```
category = set_category(flags)
#=> "obligatory fresh"
```

I think it is less obvious what flags need to be `true`/`false` for a specific category to be set, and more code is needed, but its an alternative if you don't like your current approach.

Answer (score -2):

Category = category_helper(optional, taken, active, cooldown, locked)
Category_helper
If !optional && taken && active && !cooldown && !locked
  'Obligatoeytaken'
Elsif ...
Elsif optional && taken

First list if with the highest number of arguments

Comment: This answer is incomplete and without the proper format.